# does gcc 5 compile fork() return parent pid 0?

Tags: c, gcc, fork, pid

i'm doing my homework at linux mint (which has gcc 7.4.0)
but homework testing environment was ubuntu 16.04 (which has gcc 5.4.0)

it was homwork about fork and related code is like this

```
pid_t pids[total_process_num], pid;
int run_process = 0;
while (run_process < total_process_num) {
    pids[run_process] = fork();
    if(pids[run_process] < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(pids[run_process] == 0){
        break;      //child
    }
    else if(run_process == total_process_num){
        break;
    }
    run_process++;
}
printf("fork value and pid is %d, %ld\n", run_process,(long) pids[run_process]);
```

this code print if total process number is 5 than
in my environment(if gcc 7.4 make execution file) result is

```
fork value and pid is 1, 0
fork value and pid is 0, 0
fork value and pid is 2, 0
fork value and pid is 5, 32766
fork value and pid is 4, 0
fork value and pid is 3, 0
```

in testing environment(if gcc 5.4 make execution file) result is

```
fork value and pid is 0, 0
fork value and pid is 1, 0
fork value and pid is 2, 0
fork value and pid is 5, 0
fork value and pid is 3, 0
fork value and pid is 4, 0
```

so why this difference occur? is this because of gcc version difference?
i thought always fork returns parent to value not 0
since this result below code do not work

if (pids[run_process] != 0)
parent process enter this if statement in gcc 7.4 but not in 5.4
i don't think gcc 5.4 is bad, so i want to know the reason of this result

Comment: `fork()` is a standard POSIX function, it doesn't depend on the GCC version.

Comment: Think - what is the value of `run_process` in parent when loop finishes? And therefore the value of `pids[run_process]`

Comment: `if(run_process == total_process_num)` will never be true, because the `while` loop stops before it gets that high.

Answer (score 1):

When the parent executes the `printf()`, it's printing an element of the array that you never assigned to.

The last iteration of the loop assigned to `pids[4]`. The child breaks out of the loop, but the parent executes `run_process++;`, so `run_process` is now `5`. Then the `while()` condition ends the loop.

So the parent tries to print `pids[5]`, but this was never assigned during the loop. Printing an unassigned value causes undefined behavior, so it's not surprising that you get different results from different compilers.